# How to make jQuery Accordion open at the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui-accordion

How do you customize the jQuery Accordion to open on top of an element instead of on under it?

I placed a Search icon in my navigation menu and my goal is to open the accordion on top of the **Search icon** when you click it.

On my [website](http://shop.artmusicsex.com), the Search icon is currently inactive.

I want it to look and function as it does on [this website](http://thehundreds.com/shop/).

Click on the Search Icon and watch how the accordion springs on top of the page.

```
$("#search-accordion1").awsAccordion({
    type: "vertical",
    cssAttrsVer: {
        ulWidth: "responsive",
        liHeight: 50
    },
    startSlide: false,
    openCloseHelper: {
        openIcon: "ok-circle",
        closeIcon: "ok-sign"
    },
    openOnebyOne:true,
    classTab: "active",
    slideOn: "click",
    autoPlay: false,
    autoPlaySpeed: 2000
})
```

Answer (score 0):

May be all you need is to use the jQuery .slideDown().